# Difference between Ethereumj and Web3j and how to connect private Ethereum network

Tags: private-blockchain, ethereumj

I want to develop a Spring MVC web application that use a private Ethereum network and I feel confused witch API to use Ethereumj or Web3j. I'd like to know the difference between them and how to connect my local blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

You should choose **Web3j**. Because, you want to create application that uses blockchain, being its client.

According official docs:

Web3j - is a [client library](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/connecting-to-clients/web3j/index.html).

EthereumJ - is the [blockchain node](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/ethereumj/index.html) itself